# Login control with Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Gooday, I would like to use the `<Login>` and `<asp:CreateUserWizard >` with sessions, is it possible?

I know how to check if the username and password textboxes from a Login control should trigger a session, it should be something like this:

```
TextBox userTextBox = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
TextBox userPassword = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("Password");


if (User1.ConnAttempt(userTextBox.Text, userPassword.Text) == 1)
{
      Session["User"] = userTextBox.Text;
}
```

The ConnAttempt method here is defined elsewhere and checks the Clients database table for the specified credentials, returning 1 if they exist.
**But how does the system know to actually "log in" after the Login button is pressed?**

I should mention I had roles and users configured previously through the Web Site Administration tool, which I am now trying to do without (get rid of) for various reasons, and I am unsure on how to do the transition quickest and most easily. Thanks a lot!
Anna

Comment: But how does the system know to actually "log in" after the Login button is pressed? Through Authentication.

Comment: But what should I change to go from "Web Site Administration tool" usage for Roles and users to: storing roles and user in an Sql Server database? In this example here, of the Login Control, clicking the LOGIN button will make the system check if the credentials exist in the Web Site Admin, but I want to check instead if they exist in the database and connect that with the controls.

Comment: It will work, but how much security you intend to provide? Sessions variables can be vulnerable and are discouraged. Otherwise, the modal you described will work fine. Just make sure password stored is encrypted :).